# Parsing XML to arraylist in Android

Tags: android, xml-parsing, here-api

I am trying to create a list/Array of data to be stored and send as input to function. But i am not able to do it can some one help me.
I am new to Andriod development.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.xmlread;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.util.Log;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
 import java.util.ArrayList;

   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   TextView tv1;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    XmlPullParserFactory pullParserFactory;


    try {
        pullParserFactory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        XmlPullParser parser = pullParserFactory.newPullParser();

        InputStream in_s = 
   getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("demo.xml");
        parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);

        parser.setInput(in_s, null);
        ArrayList<FIS> fis=  parseXML(parser);
        String text = "";
        for(FIS fi:fis)
        {

            text+= "Route : "+fi.getDE()+" Distance(KM) : "+fi.getLE()+" 
   Traffic Jam : "+fi.getJF()+"Speed"+fi.getSP()+"\n";
        }
        Log.d("text",text);
        tv1.setText(text);

    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

 }

   private ArrayList<FIS> parseXML(XmlPullParser parser) throws 
  XmlPullParserException,IOException
   {
    ArrayList<FIS> fis = null;
    int eventType = parser.getEventType();
    FIS fi = null;

    while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){
        String de;
        switch (eventType){
            case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
                fis = new ArrayList();
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                //de = parser.getDE();
                 if (fi != null){
                    if (fi.equals("DE")){
                        fi.DE = parser.nextText();
                    } else if (fi.equals("LE")){
                        fi.LE = parser.nextText();
                    }
                    else if (fi.equals("JF")){
                        fi.JF = parser.nextText();
                    }
                    else if (fi.equals("SP")){
                        fi.SP = parser.nextText();
                    }

                }
                break;

        }
        eventType = parser.next();
    }

    return fis;

  }

  }
```

This xml file is been added to assets folder as well.
MyXML File is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<TRAFFICML_REALTIME xmlns="http://traffic.nokia.com/trafficml-flow-3.2" 
CREATED_TIMESTAMP="2019-03-19T11:54:51Z" MAP_VERSION="" UNITS="metric" 
VERSION="3.2">
<RWS TY="TMC" MAP_VERSION="201901" EBU_COUNTRY_CODE="5" 
  EXTENDED_COUNTRY_CODE="F2" TABLE_ID="3" UNITS="metric">
    <RW LI="503-00011" DE="100 Feet Main Road" PBT="2019-03-19T11:54:49Z" 
    mid="4e2460ff-07bb-44a1-844a-3f9772b0165b">
        <FIS>
            <FI>
                <TMC PC="14" DE="jnhddggfg" QD="+" LE="0.05949"/>
                <CF CN="0.7" FF="27.0" JF="7.55161" SP="10.0" SU="10.0" 
   TY="TR"/>
            </FI>
            <FI>
                <TMC PC="13" DE="29th Main Road" QD="+" LE="0.77418"/>
                <CF CN="0.7" FF="28.0" JF="7.80008" SP="10.0" SU="10.0" 
     TY="TR"/>
            </FI>
            <FI>
                <TMC PC="12" DE="28th Main Road" QD="+" LE="0.0493"/>
                <CF CN="0.7" FF="26.0" JF="5.61675" SP="13.0" SU="13.0" 
   TY="TR"/>
            </FI>
        </FIS>
    </RW>
 <RW LI="503-00011" DE="100 Feet Main Road" PBT="2019-03-19T11:54:49Z" 
   mid="4e2460ff-07bb-44a1-844a-3f9772b0165b">
        <FIS>
            <FI>
                <TMC PC="14" DE="jnhddggfg" QD="+" LE="0.05949"/>
                <CF CN="0.7" FF="27.0" JF="7.55161" SP="10.0" SU="10.0" 
         TY="TR"/>
            </FI>
            <FI>
                <TMC PC="13" DE="29th Main Road" QD="+" LE="0.77418"/>
                <CF CN="0.7" FF="28.0" JF="7.80008" SP="10.0" SU="10.0" 
                TY="TR"/>
            </FI>
            <FI>
                <TMC PC="12" DE="28th Main Road" QD="+" LE="0.0493"/>
                <CF CN="0.7" FF="26.0" JF="5.61675" SP="13.0" SU="13.0" 
 TY="TR"/>
            </FI>
        </FIS>
    </RW>
    </RWS>
    </TRAFFICML_REALTIME>
```

I want this data stored in XML to Display and store data into arraylist in Android.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Was there a particular reason why you chose to work with the xmlpull library? I don't know too much about that library but how did you go about creating your models for this xml structure (maybe the library maybe does it for you automatically)? For starters, your FIS data class is a child of RW. That said, why are you creating an ArrayList of FIS?

Comment: @rj2700 I could fix it by myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is:

MainActivity.java

```
 ArrayList<Fuel> fueldata=  parseXML(parser);
        ArrayList<String> len = null;
                len = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList<String> jf = null;
        jf = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList<String> speed = null;
        speed = new ArrayList();


        String text="";
        for(Fuel mapdata:fueldata)
        {
            len.add(mapdata.getLE());
            jf.add(mapdata.getJF());
            speed.add(mapdata.getSP());

        }

        text = Fuel_Economy(len,jf,speed);
        textView.setText(text);
```